# Strange behaviour of takeRight() with ListBuffer in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, collections

I have a scala ListBuffer and 2 variables as follows:

```
    val parmsList = s.getBatchPARMS(a, sampleSize, batchnumber, queryName, resStr,rdocGlob, blend, pss,iterations,run_start,meta_start)
    var meta_start = 0
    var run_start = 0`
```

`parmsList` prints like:

```
ListBuffer("c1", "Q9tHuman9tHealthM2tHuman0kOP>20N|20N", "e43g68t10f4i2cs40", "4.6.2.2", "5e47e7ccaeb977af8a64b88a", "c1.Q9tHuman9tHealthM2tHuman0kOP>20N|20N.e43g68t10f4i2cs40-13244.1", "1", "10" , "1", "732514", "39281", 1)
```

I then do:

```
val parmsListDropped = parmsList.dropRight(1)            
val ids = parmsListDropped.takeRight(2)
meta_start = ids(1).toInt
run_start = ids(0).toInt
```

Which fails with:

```
[error] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
```

When I print `ids` I get:

```
ListBuffer("c1", "Q9tHuman9tHealthM2tHuman0kOP>20N|20N", "e43g68t10f4i2cs40", "4.6.2.2", "5e47e7ccaeb977af8a64b88a", "c1.Q9tHuman9tHealthM2tHuman0kOP>20N|20N.e43g68t10f4i2cs40-13244.1", "1", "10" , "1", "732514", "39281")
```

Which doesn't seem right at all...

Even weirder, when I do all this step by step in the scala shell I get:

```
scala> val b = ListBuffer("c1", "Q9tHuman9tHealthM2tHuman0kOP>20N|20N", "e43g68t10f4i2cs40", "4.6.2.2", "5e47e7ccaeb977af8a64b88a", "c1.Q9tHuman9tHealthM2tHuman0kOP>20N|20N.e43g68t10f4i2cs40-13244.1", "1", "10" , "1", "732514", "39281")
b: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer(c1, Q9tHuman9tHealthM2tHuman0kOP>20N|20N, e43g68t10f4i2cs40, 4.6.2.2, 5e47e7ccaeb977af8a64b88a, c1.Q9tHuman9tHealthM2tHuman0kOP>20N|20N.e43g68t10f4i2cs40-13244.1, 1, 10, 1, 732514, 39281)

scala> b.takeRight(2)
res5: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer(732514, 39281)
```

As you'd expect.

I'm using Scala 2.11 inside Apache Spark 2.2.0 with some Java Conversions on macOS Mojave 10.14.5. Here are my imports:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

import com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark
import org.bson.Document
import org.bson.types.ObjectId
import com.mongodb.spark.rdd.api.java.JavaMongoRDD
import com.mongodb.spark.rdd.MongoRDD
import com.mongodb.spark.config._

import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD
import java.util._
import org.apache.spark.api.java._

import net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats
import net.liftweb.json._
import net.liftweb.json.JsonDSL._

import java.util.ArrayList

import scalaj.http._
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: where does spark play a role here? Are you using spark-shell/spark-submit? Is your code in a UDF?

Comment: @RaphaelRoth The code is running in a local cluster on my machine - the production environment is a remote cluster. It might not be relevant, just thought I'd give as much detail as possible